# How to make Silverlight datafrom Commit button enabled when I have data binding on textbox from foreign key and text in text box is edited

Tags: silverlight, dataform

I am using SL4, RIA toolkit Spt 2011, SP1. MVVM

When my text box is directly from the parent table, upon change on the text the commit button gets enabled but when the text box is from the foreign key and when we changes are there submit buttons still remains disabled.

Have read this [DataForm commit button is not enabled when data changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467441/dataform-commit-button-is-not-enabled-when-data-changed) which is not similar to my problem.

my database table look likes

> Customertable (name, IdEmail) and EmailTable(IdEmail, Email)

Dataform is like:

---

Name: _____________

Email: _____________

```
  |submit| |Cancel|
```

---

But cancel button is always active. I want submit button to be active when ever i have some changes in email. however if i have changes in name the submit button get enabled and i could also save the changes in email after that.

Both Name and email has two way binding with viewmodel.

for example view model is like

```
 private ObservableCollection<Customertable > _customer
public ObservableCollection<Customertable > Customer
{
   get return _customer;
}
  set{
     if(_customer == value) return;
    _customer = value;
    RaisedProtertyChanged("Customer");
}
```

Email field in above "view" is binded into "Customer.EmailTable.Email"

Or is only way to solve this is to make my own custom submit and cancel button?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm taking a couple shots in the dark. I assume you're beginning an edit or putting the form in add-new mode, since your cancel button is active? If that's not the issue, the easiest fix is probably manually enabling (and disabling, if needed) the submit button. Perhaps doing so with VisualTreeHelper, as suggested in [this SL forums thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/235739.aspx/1) would do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I am looking forward to use built in commit and cancel button for DataForm (CommandButtonsVisibility ="commit, cancel" )

Comment: @webKite - My apologies, apparently my reading comprehension is awful. I'll edit my answer to be something that's hopefully more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Old question for outdated technology. Perfect time to answer:
Extend the Dataform so that the command button is always enabled.

```
public class CustomDataForm : DataForm
{
  private Button _commitButton;
  protected override void OnContentLoaded(DataFormContentLoadEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnContentLoaded(e);
    var dependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0) as Grid;
    _commitButton = dependencyObject?.FindName("CommitButton") as Button;
    if (_commitButton == null) return;
    _commitButton.IsEnabled = true;
    _commitButton.IsEnabledChanged += (s, e1) =>
      {
        if (!(bool) e1.NewValue)
          _commitButton.IsEnabled = true;
      };
  }  
}
```